# How to remove spaces from array using Ruby

Tags: ruby

Arr= ["abcd","1223","  10829380","pqrs"]

I want to print array like this-

```
Arr=["abcd","1223","10829380","pqrs"]
```

Comment: Not sure if this is intended but `Arr` is a constant. If you wanted to have a local variable, it should be `arr` (lowercase).

Answer (score 4):

You should follow naming patterns and not use `Arr` as this usually is used 
for class names.

```
arr = ["abcd","1223"," 10829380","pqrs"]
whitespace_removed_arr = arr.map { |item| item.strip }
```

`map` iterates the array of strings (`arr`) and builds a new array containing the return values of the block.

You can use the shorter version if you like:

```
arr = ["abcd","1223"," 10829380","pqrs"]
whitespace_removed_arr = arr.map(&:strip)
```

Please note that the solutions proposing `strip!` and `map` (inplace version iof `strip`) will most likely not work or work in a confusing way since `strip!` (oddly enough) returns `nil` when the string was not changed.

```
"".strip => ""
"".strip! => nil
"".strip => ""
" ".strip! => ""
```

If you want to use the inplace variant of strip and modify the original array you will need to use `each`

```
arr.each(&:strip!)
```

`each` discards the return value from the block, and `strip!` modifies the string in place.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `arr.map { |item| item.strip }`does not work because the result is discarded. `arr.map!{ |item| item.strip }` does work.

Comment: The difference here is that `map` is non-destructive, whereas `map!` modifies in place - mutating the variable. The proposed solution by @pascalbetz is imo the best solution. You just need to bind the return value to a variable e.g. `arr = arr.map(&:strip)`. In this case we are re-binding `arr` to the return value of calling `map` on `arr`.

Comment: @steenslag thanks for the hint. I improved my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Array#map!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21) or [Array.map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map). `Array#map!` changes the original array and `Array#map` returns a new array so the original array keeps unchanged. The `map` functions iterate about the array and execute the given block for each element in the array.

```
arr = ["abcd", "1223", " 10829380", "pqrs"]
arr.map!{ |el| el.strip }
arr
# => ["abcd", "1223", "10829380", "pqrs"]

# or

arr = ["abcd", "1223", " 10829380", "pqrs"]
arr.map{ |el| el.strip }
# => ["abcd", "1223", "10829380", "pqrs"]
arr
# => ["abcd", "1223", " 10829380", "pqrs"]
```

Btw: Variables in ruby begin with a lowercase letter or _ (`arr`).

Comment: Why the `!`?, the empty parenthesis?

Comment: @SebastianPalma: Please see my explanation in the updated answer.